# OS X Server location of Xcode Provisioning Profiles?

Tags: xcode, osx-server, xcode-bots, xcode-server

My OS X Server Xcode Bot gives the error:

> Bot Issue: warning. Build Service Error.
>
> Issue: No matching provisioning profile found: Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with the UUID “XYZ-123"
>
> Description: No matching provisioning profile found: Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with the UUID “XYZ-123”, however, no such provisioning profile was found.

Where is OS X Server looking for the Provisioning Profiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS X Server Xcode Provisioning Profile directory is:

**Current:**

`/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/ManagedProfiles/`

**Legacy:**

`/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/ProvisioningProfiles`
`/Library/Server/Xcode/Data/ProvisioningProfiles`

*Please edit this answer if it becomes out of date in a future version of Xcode.*